# Return column if another column is 3, otherwise return 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am able to create a query that searches "column 2" in "table 1" for the value "3", and return a value in a separate "column 1"

```
SELECT [Column 2]
FROM [Table 1]
WHERE [Column 1] = 3
```

However, I do not know how to have the query return a "0" if "3" is not found - any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 0 else max(column2) end) as has_3
from table1
where column1 = 3;
```

Or more simply:

```
select coalesce(max(column2), 0)
from table1
where column1 = 3;
```

Comment: Where do you reference column 2? There are multiple columns, but only want column 2 returned.

Comment: @user14750197 . . . What if there are multiple values?

Comment: If there are multiple "3" values in Column 1, then only return the column 2 value that was entered last in the table (furthest down on the table).

Comment: Looks like you're edit worked:

SELECT(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE MAX(Column 2) end) as Column 2
FROM [Table 1]
where Column 1 = 3

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case`:

```
select
  case
    when column1 = 3 then column2
    else 0
  end as column2
FROM table1
```

Comment: Looks like this returns an array as if all the values in column 2 are "0" and then returns the actual value in Colum 2 where Column 1 = 3

Comment: Not sure what you mean; this looks to me like it does exactly what you ask (though the other question had a completely different idea of what you asked).  Add some sample data and expected results for that sample data to your question